# Error Occurs When Deleting Cell with Animation

Tags: iphone, uitableview

```
[[PeopleManager shared] removePersonAtIndex:indexPath.row withGroupIndex:currentGroupIndex];

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

PeopleManager Class have a people array (NSMutableArray).

My error is not Index value error.

It works fine 99.9% without error. But sometimes error occur

**Error Code**

> 2012-02-03 17:17:53.232 PhoneBook[343:707] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046
>       2012-02-03 17:17:53.239 PhoneBook[343:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
>       terminate called throwing an exceptionkill

How can fix it??? I read error code.but I do not know how to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wrap your deleteRows... call in a beginUpdates and endUpdates pair:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

and make sure that your numberOfRowsForSection: method returns the correct updated value